ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_bootstrap5accounts'
I just installed django-crispy-forms and crispy-bootstrap5. Then I followed the official website guide into updating the "setting.py" file then when I run the server from "python manage.py runserver" I got this error "crispy_bootstrap5accounts". I tried searching it online but I couldn't find any answers.
Here is the whole error message ->
error-message full
I tried
INSTALLED_APPS = [
"django.contrib.admin",
"django.contrib.auth",
"django.contrib.contenttypes",
"django.contrib.sessions",
"django.contrib.messages",
"django.contrib.staticfiles",
"crispy_forms", # new
"crispy_bootstrap5", # new
]

and
CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = "bootstrap5"
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap5"

But it didn't help

I was having the same issue but with the module 'crispy_bootstrap5django'
I just realized that the crispy module tries to get the "django" module with the "crispy_bootstrap5django" name. I solved it the laziest way possible, duplicating the django module and naming it as the crispy_module was requiring.
Looks like the crispy_bootstrap5 version isn't very stable.
